# Does this barbershop semaphore solution have a bug?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, semaphore, pseudocode

I have come up with a pseudocode solution to the barbershop problem.

Requirements- a customer can call gethaircut() and a barber can call cuthair() and theres n seats available.
A barber should be sleeping until a customer calls gethaircut.
If n seats are taken then the customer should call balk() which just exits that customer thread.
The methods gethaircut and cuthair should be only running in parallel with one thread of each caller, meaning only one thread should be calling cuthair while another thread is calling gethaircut.

There is only one barber.

Here is the solution I came up with.. I really cannot format this correctly on the phone.. Please bear with

// Sem = semaphore. Sry Im on my phone

Int n = maxSeats

Sem mutex = new Sem(1)

Sem hairCutMutex = new Sem(1)

Sem canCutHair = new Sem(0)

Sem finishedHairCut = new Sem(0)

Customer() {

```
P(mutex)

   if (n == 0) {

      V(mutex)

       balk();

   }

V(mutex)
```

P(hairCutMutex)

```
 getHairCut()

 V(canCutHair)

 P(finishedHairCut)
```

V(hairCutMutex)

P(mutex)

```
  n++
```

V(mutex)

}

---

`Barber() {

while (true) {

```
 P(canCutHair)

    cutHair()

    V(finishedHairCut)
```

}
}
`

Comment: why do you use a phone ? need help for your exam ?

Comment: No, I alreadg graduated a while back 
After work, I have to be outside of home without wifi